# Windows Live ID Compliance Guide

Tags: 2013, sts, sharepoint-server

I've been following this guide to set up Windows Live ID authentication (http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Visual-guide-to-Windows-Live-ID-authentication-with-SharePoint-2010-part-1.aspx) and it makes mention to a compliance guide (https://msm.live.com/Help/Lookup.aspx?Keyword=CriteriaAndCases).

I've have tried for several days to download this guide but I keep getting a system error.

Does anyone have a copy of this guide? Right now, we are building an integration of Windows Live ID into our SharePoint 2013 (yes, 2013 but we're using the 2010 guide) but have no idea of the standards that we should be meeting.

***Update:** Having talked to various sources at Microsoft, I've still be unable to lay my hands on a copy of this guide. If anyone has anything that can help, that would be awesome.*

Can anyone help?

Cheers, and thanks for reading.